# Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, system.reflection

I am working on a WPF application an I receive this error only at run time on single device.

```
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

My question:

- Any clue of  what  could be cause this error?
- Any idea how to debug the application in release mode?

---

```
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(System.TimeSpan)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.TimeSpan)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at WPF.DataModel.WPFDataSource.LoadData()
   at WPF.DataModel.WPFDataSource.DownloadNewData(Boolean)
   at WPF.DataModel.WPFDataSource.Load(Boolean)
   at WPF.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at WPF.App.Main()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is a wrapper exception that simply tells you that a reflection `.Invoke()` (or similar) failed. To find out what *actually* failed, you need to look at the wrapped exception, via `.InnerException`. That contains the *real* error.

So: where-ever you are catching that, just check `ex.InnerException`. And the `.InnerException` of that, if one, etc - all the way down.

Answer (score 5):

You should put this part of code inside try/catch block and catch TargetInvocationException and see the inner exception it will give you more detailed reason

This exception can provide more information what the problem is and it means the reflection .Invoke() failed.

For more information :-

As suggested in official site here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828991 :-

> You receive the System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException error
>   because the common language runtime calls the MethodInfo.Invoke method
>   by using reflection.
>
> When you load an assembly by using the Assembly.LoadFrom method, the
>   common language runtime places the loaded assembly in the LoadFrom
>   context of your application. Any probes for the dependencies of the
>   assembly first probe the current application directory. If this probe
>   fails, the common language runtime then probes the LoadFrom context of
>   your application.
>
> You may load an assembly that has a simply-named dependency that has
>   the same file name as a file in the current application directory.
>   When you try to invoke a method in the loaded assembly by using the
>   MethodInfo.Invoke method, and the invoked method uses the dependency,
>   the common language runtime first probes the current directory path.
>   When the common language runtime finds a file that has the same file
>   name as the dependency, the probe stops. However, if this file does
>   not have the same assembly identity as the dependency, the assembly
>   bind fails, and the common language runtime generates a
>   System.IO.FileLoadException error that is passed to the
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException error. Therefore, you may
>   notice the behavior that is mentioned in the "Symptoms" section.