# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException when i run MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Suddenly i'm not able to my mvc4 application.
I didn't do any change in the code. any idea where and how can i solve this issue? or have more information to trace this issue?

I restarted my PC a couple of times, also checked these articles

1. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120176/exception-info-system-reflection-targetinvocationexception)
2. [Ms](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828991)

They suggest to check the part of code that causes this. but in my case i don't even arrive to any of my code.

The folder mentioned by Intelitrace is empty:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files

Inner exception message:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146232828   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>          at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1
>   methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures)
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods)
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
>          at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
>          at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
>          at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel)
>          at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel)
>          at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String
>   appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters
>   hostingParameters)
>          at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String
>   appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters
>   hostingParameters)
>          at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String
>   appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters
>   hostingParameters)
>          at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectInternal(String
>   appId, Type type, IApplicationHost appHost, Boolean failIfExists,
>   HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
>          at System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.StartApplication(String appId, String appPath, Object& runtimeInterface)   InnerException:
>   System.AccessViolationException
>          HResult=-2147467261
>          Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>          StackTrace:
>          InnerException:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how i solved this issue,

1. Uninstall Visual studio 2012
2. Uninstall all .NET .
3. Restart
4. Install Latest .Net
5. Install Visual studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961803/6138713)

> Finally tracked this down with the help of WinDBG and SOS. Access
>   violation was being thrown by some unknown DLL. Turns out a piece of
>   software called "Nvidia Network Manager" was causing the problems. I'd
>   read countless times how this issue can be caused by firewalls or
>   antivirus, neither of which I am using so I dismissed this idea. Also,
>   I was under the assumption that it was not environmental because it
>   occurs on more than 1 server using different hardware. Turns out all
>   the machines I tested this on were running "NVidia Network Manager". I
>   believe it installs with the rest of the motherboard drivers.

Which may be an issue that is outside of your application. In this guy's case there's a bad software that's affecting his application. You might wanna try tracking it with the tools he mentioned. Good luck!